# compass cannot load such file sass_extemsions.rb

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I installed compass via gem install compass

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\project\webfeature>gem install compass
Fetching: sass-3.2.19.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.2.19
Fetching: compass-0.12.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed compass-0.12.6
Parsing documentation for sass-3.2.19
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.2.19
Parsing documentation for compass-0.12.6
Installing ri documentation for compass-0.12.6
2 gems installed
```

Looks fine, doesn´t it?
But when i try to run it via gruntjs with "grunt dev" it does not work, says it cannot load the file sass_extensions.rb, although it is exactly there ...

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
LoadError on line ["55"] of C: cannot load such file -- src/sass/libs/sass_extensions.rb
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running Compass without grunt?

Comment: yes, when i  run compass compile i get the same error ...

Comment: This may be important:in my config.rb there is a line saying:
    `require File.join('src/sass/libs', 'sass_extensions.rb')`
But the file is in this directory relative to the dir with the config.rb ...

Comment: Ok i needed to address the absolute link ... 
i got the project like this from somebody and apparently it worked for him with the relative path ... if someone can give me a hint how that can be possible or where i can configurate this, i´d be thankful